Помогите вспомнить слово, выхлестнуло!)
КАК СКАЗАТЬ ОДНИМ СЛОВОМ: "Я даю тебе ....." (право на вседозволенность, полную свободу выбора, привилегию творить, что хочешь и т.п.)
Кажется, это слово имеет не русские корни.
По ощущениям что-то похожее на "Пойти ва-банк", но это не точно)

Может, потворствовать?

Дополнение к данному ответу:  Белая карточка от короля https://dzen.ru/a/X122-TVFNQgeldAU  Карт-бланш: как с этим словом связаны французские короли?

Точно, это карт-бланш! СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ)

Карт-бланш
фр. carte blanche.
Неограниченные полномочия, полная свобода действий, предоставляемая кому-л. от имени доверителя..
